# position fixed and absolute

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap, css

I am using bootstrap to achieve the following. I have put one column as fixed however the next column is overlapping. I need only the second column to scroll.

```html
<div class="container-fluid" style="margin-top:-50px;">
  <div class="row" style="margin-top:3.75%;">
    <div class="col-sm-4" style="position:fixed;background-color: #ACD661;">
      <p>dummy textdummy textdummy textdummy textdummy textdummy textdummy textdummy textdummy text</p>
    </div>


    <div class="col-sm-8">
      <p>START TEST SOME CONTENT HERETEST SOME CONTENT HERETEST SOME CONTENT HERETEST SOME CONTENT HERETEST SOME CONTENT HERETEST SOME CONTENT HERETEST SOME CONTENT HERETEST SOME CONTENT HERETEST SOME CONTENT HERE</p>

    </div>
  </div>

  <!--end-->
```

Comment: what is it that you want actually , didn't get that. use jsFiddle  its better for checking and all.

Answer (score 0):

Using bootstrap I had a left and right column, the left column as assigned `position:fixed` however this made the content of the right column overlap with the left one. 
I managed to figured it out by simply modifying the second column to :

```html
<div class="col-sm-8 col-md-offset-4 tasks-column">
```